# How could I save generated PCM bytes[] to android supported audio file?

Tags: java, android, audio

The `bytes[]` array is generated by myself at specific frequency. And now I want to save the bytes to `.wav` file,in order that the MediaPlayer could play it.
Could anyone have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure there are libraries to do this somewhere, I normally just use my own WAV-file writing code, based on the file format described [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/). It can be a bit tricky if you want to support multiple bit-rates, etc., and you also need to bear in mind the little-endian byte order.